# Disable scroll for PDFView inside NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsscrollview, nscollectionview, pdfview

I have a PdfView inside a CollectionView. Since both have its own scrollviews I have conflicts in scrolling. So i want to disable scrolling for PdfView. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a regular Scroll View you can remove scrolls by setting horizontal & vertical scrolls to false value. So for a PDF view try this :

```
NSScrollView *enclosingScrollView = [myPdfView enclosingScrollView];
[enclosingScrollView setHasHorizontalScroller:NO];
[enclosingScrollView setHasVerticalScroller:NO];
```

Comment: I don't think this should be marked as correct. enclosingScrollView gets a parent scroll view - not the one used internally by the pdfView. Also, has..Scroller just sets whether there is a scrollbar view, not whether the scrollview actually scrolls.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is a little rough, but does work.
I only wanted to stop horizontal scrolling on my PDFViews - my collection view scrolls horizontally.

I made a view that selectively filters out the scroll mouse events and put it over the PFD view.

```
class HorizontalScrollBlockerView: NSView
{
    var scrollNextResponder: NSResponder?

    override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {
        guard scrollNextResponder != nil else {
            return
        }

        if fabs(event.deltaX) >= fabs(event.deltaY) {
            scrollNextResponder!.scrollWheel(with: event)
        } else {
            super.scrollWheel(with: event)
        }
    }
}
```

I set the view's 'scrollNextResponder' to be the superView of the PDFView.

I also wrote a method that gets the first child scroll view (enclos**ed**ScrollView) which makes sure the PDFView is solid in the horizontal axis when correctly scaled.

```
if let scrollView = pdfView.enclosedScrollView {
    scrollView.usesPredominantAxisScrolling = true
    scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = false
    scrollView.horizontalScrollElasticity = NSScrollView.Elasticity.none
}
```